# How can i have Grid with cell which can act as container in GXT 3?

Tags: grid, cell, gxt, custom-cell

How can i have Grid with cell which can act as container in GXT 3 so that they can hold any object from other container to any widget.
I'm working on small app which has **row expander grid**. GXT demo has good example of it.
From class hierarchy it was clear that Grid cells are Cell interface which allows for using `render()` method so I can add any html code that can displayed in it.
But i wanted to create a cell widget which can have `add()` method for allowing to add other widgets such as **ContentPanel** to any other widget

Any suggestion ?

Answer (score -1):

This is the code i wrote. Not a perfect one, but does the work.

```
public class MyRowExpander extends
    RowExpander<GridModel> {

public MyRowExpander (
        IdentityValueProvider<GridModel> valueProvider,
        AbstractCell<GridModel> contentCell) {
    super(valueProvider, contentCell);


}
@Override
protected boolean beforeExpand(GridModel model, Element body,
        XElement row, int rowIndex) {
    super.beforeExpand(model, body, row, rowIndex);
    BeforeExpandItemEvent<GridModel> e = new BeforeExpandItemEvent<GridModel>(
            model);
    if (!e.isCancelled()) {
        if (body.hasChildNodes())
            body.removeChild(body.getChild(0));
        body.setInnerText("");
        Widget customWidget = getWidget(model);
        body.appendChild(customWidget.getElement());
        ComponentHelper.doAttach(customWidget);
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```